# New PS3 controller won't sync with PS3

Tags: ps3, technical-issues, controllers

I bought a new six-axis controller for my best friend, and I did a custom paint job on it. I had to take it apart, but after I put everything back together (right), it just blinks the red lights when it is plugged into the PS3 via USB. Even when I press the PS button it still just blinks for a while. I've also tried to reset it by pressing the reset button on the controller, turning on the PS3, plugging in the USB, and pressing the PS button, but still nothing happens.

I am very certain I didn't harm anything inside the controller when I disassembled it. I have a PS3 Slim if that is any help. Any idea what could be wrong and what I should do to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried in that order ?

1. Plug the USB port on the controller to the PS3
2. Turn on the PS3
3. Reset the controller
4. Turn it on with the PS3 button in the middle
5. Unplug it

It happened to me once and that worked!

I think the problem might be because you've reset the controller before turning on the PS3 plugged in.

If not, I think something might be damaged since you're opened it to paint. :S

Comment: Nope that didn't work, but when I plug the controller in via USB the lights flash only when I hit the ps button, but they only flash for a minute or so. Anything else? Cause the lights flashing means it works right?

Comment: List flashing only means that the Bluetooth is active and scanning for any device to connect too. So if it's flashing even with the USB cable plugged, then it might be broken :S

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that you use the correct charging cable as I had major on-going issue like that until I read about using the heavier-duty cable that came with the PS3.